# cast Nullable to ValueType

Tags: c#, nullable

Is there any difference between `Nullable.Value` and `(<whatEverType>) Nullable`? As far as I know both methods return NULL if the value is not set or the value itself.

e.g:

```
DateTime? date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now = (DateTime) date;
DateTime now2 = date.Value;
```

Comment: Can you provide compiling code?

Comment: "both methods return NULL if the value is not set or the value itself." nope. It throws `InvalidOperationException` in both cases when value is not set.

Comment: _"As far as I know both methods return NULL"_ Now that you've already provided the compiling code, why haven't you verified this statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, there is no difference. You will get `InvalidOperationException` in both cases when value is not set.
What is more, here is implementation of the cast operator inside `Nullable<T>`:

```
public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
    return value.Value;
}
```

(decompiled with Resharper)

So the cast operator uses the `Value` member.

Comment: Aaaah, Thanks for this answer... I missed the exception being thrown when value is not set.

Comment: Not sure if it is due to inlining or cleverness, but the compiler gets the `Value` member in both cases.

Comment: @IllidanS4 I thinks that it is due to inlining.